# php цикл вывод в массив

Tags: php

Есть такой код:

```
$c = 0.4; 
$m = 50; 
$g = 9.81; 
$S = 2; 
$p = 1; 
$V = 20; 

$k2 = (0.5)*$c*$S*$p;

for ($x = 0; $x <= 14; $x += 0.5) {

    $y = (0.5)*(($m*$g-$k2*(pow($V, 2)))*(pow($x, 2)) / $m);

}
```

Как сделать вот такой вывод массива?:

```
$arr = array(
    array("x"=> 0.5,    "y"=> 0.82),
    array("x"=> 1,      "y"=> 3.3),
    array("x"=> 1.5,    "y"=> 7.43),
    ...
    array("x"=> 14,     "y"=> 647.78)
);
```

Comment: Добавлять в массив нужные элементы. Умеете добавлять в массив или документацию лень читать?

Comment: @u_mulder не умею, вот и задал вопрос

Comment: документация: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php или прям вот что надо http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = 0.4; $m = 50; $g = 9.81; $S = 2; $p = 1; $V = 20; $k2 = (0.5) * $c * $S * $p;

for ($x = 0; $x <= 14; $x += 0.5) { 
    $y = (0.5) * (($m * $g - $k2 * (pow($V, 2))) * (pow($x, 2)) / $m);
    $data[] = ['x' => $x, 'y' => $y];
}

print_r($data);
```